Tight upper bound for $E[XYZ]$ in terms of $L_2$ norm
If it is just $E[XY]$, then I can apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which is a special case of Holder's inequality to get
$$E[XY] \le |E[XY]| \le E[|XY|] \le (E[X^2])^{1/2}(E[Y^2])^{1/2} = \|X\|_2\|Y\|_2$$.
However, now I want to upper bound $E[XYZ]$. My first thought is applying CS inequality twice:
\begin{align*}
E[XYZ] &= E[(XY)Z]\\
&\le (E[(XY)^2])^{1/2}(E[(Z^2])^{1/2}\\
&\le (E[X^4])^{1/4}(E[Y^4])^{1/4}(E[(Z^2])^{1/2}\\
&= \|X\|_4 \|Y\|_4\|Z\|_2
\end{align*}
while understanding that $\|\cdot\|_4 \ge \|\cdot\|_2$.
Another thought is using $\|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_1\|g\|_{\infty}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is the essential supremum.
\begin{align*}
E[XYZ] &\le \|Z\|_{\infty} E[|XY|] \\
&= \|Z\|_{\infty}\|X\|_2\|Y\|_2
\end{align*}
But having $\|Z\|_{\infty}$ in the upper bound is not desired especially in my application.
Before I give up, may I ask if there is anyway to get the tighter bound? I'm trying to make $\|\cdot\|_2$ in my upper bound as much as possible while avoiding having essential supremum. And I'm not working with counting measure, but probability measure.
If it is not possible, is there any special case? Or some reasonable scarification?

Such a bound would imply $XYZ\in L^3$ while only having each be $L^2$.

Why don't you try out some examples and see if such a bound using only $L^{2}$ is possible or not. For example, take the probability space to be $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B})$ and take $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)=Z(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega^{1/3}}$ for all $\omega\in[0,1]$ .

@Andrew may I ask what bound are you referring to? $|X|_2 |Y|_2 |Z|_2$? suppose $X,Y,Z \in L^3 \subset L2$.
